# Calling another function and setting if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if i can call another function also pass in if statement instruction within another function.

I need to do it this way, because i am also allowing users to select the value from a select button.

```
<script>
    $(document).one("pageshow", "#testpage", function () {


        var status = getURLParameter("status");
        var status2 = status.substring(0, status.indexOf('?'));

        if (status2 == "ready") {
            getComboA(3)
        }
    });

    function getComboA(sel) {
        var value = sel.value;
        if (value == 1) {
            alert("1 is working");
        }

        if (value == 2) {
            alert("2 is working");
        }

        if (value == 3) {
            alert("3 is working");
        }
    }
</script>

<select name="select-native-1" id="statusselect" onchange="getComboA(this)" style="width: 300px;">
    <option value="1" id="radio-choice-h-222">Not Ready</option>
    <option value="2" id="radio-choice-h-2a">Sent</option>
    <option value="3" id="radio-choice-h-2b">Ready</option>
</select>
```

The getComboA(3) part isnt working at the moment, it isnt triggering the getComboA

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Any Error in `console`? You're using `jQuery`?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? You are also missing the closing braces for that function.

Comment: no error. Just not setting the getComboA(3)

Comment: I am not sure if i can set it this way, setting the value of another function from another function. Because it isnt calling any error at the moment, also not doing anything.

Comment: You should explain what your code is supposed to do. Right now the function checks the value but does absolutely nothing because there is no code in the then-branches. What are you intending to do?

Comment: You mean in the if (value == 3) {} I just didnt include those in the above because the actual code is too long and isnt relevant. Can treat it as an alert(), but the alert isnt even triggered.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var value = sel.value;
```

to

```
var value = sel.value || sel;
```

so if `sel.value` was undefined it will use `sel`

Answer (score 0):

The answer that another user provided worked, but that whole answer got deleted. But if i use `getComboA({value:3});` it works.